# HTML with <blockquote> tags in UITextView

Tags: html, ios, uitextview, nsattributedstring

I want to display HTML text with `<blockquote>` tags in the `UITextView`.

**example of HTML:**

```
<div>
    <blockquote class="uncited">
        <div>
            <cite>Nick:</cite>
            <blockquote class="uncited">
                <div>
                    <cite>Tom:</cite>censored<br>
                    Hello
                </div>
             </blockquote>
             <p>World</p>
         </div>
    </blockquote>
    <p>Text</p>
</div>
```

I use the following code to display HTML text in the cell:

```
UITextView *textView = (UITextView*)[cell viewWithTag:100];

NSAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[thisComment.htmlText dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding] options:@{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType } documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
textView.attributedText = attributedString;
```

But in the `UITextView` it's looks like plain text. I want to get it: [sample](http://content.screencast.com/users/VityOK/folders/Jing/media/e870f372-9c03-4386-8189-3e43e694a62f/2014-05-01_1725.png)
How can i do this? What kind of libraries should i use? i think about `HTML -> Markdown -> NSAttributedString -> TextView`

Comment: You can use a WebView to show it, instead of a UITextView..

Comment: @Pach Yes, i can, but I have to display about 100 cells and it would be too slow when scrolling.

Comment: Maybe this project can help you further: https://github.com/Cocoanetics/DTCoreText

Comment: Hi, i'm having same problem. How did you fix this ?

Comment: Questions is rather old, but [here is the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41691957/2529869)

Comment: @NosovPavel this is not answer how to render vertical lines in string.

Answer (score 2):

Apple's HTML to AttributedText parser is excellent with CSS so you can actually write it like you'd do for a raw web client.

```
let parsedCommentHTML = html.replacingOccurrences(of: "<blockquote>\n", with: "<blockquote>\n<k style=\"color:#ccc; font-size: 2em; font-family: 'Copperplate'\">“</k>")
let blockQuoteCSS = "\nblockquote > p {color:#808080; display: inline;} \n blockquote { background: #f9f9f9;}"
let pCSS = "p {margin-bottom: 0px;}"
let cssStyle = "\(blockQuoteCSS)\n\(pCSS)\n"

return try NSAttributedString(data: ("<html><head><style>\(cssStyle)</style></head><span style=\"font-family: HelveticaNeue-Thin; font-size: 17\">\(CONTENT)</span></html>").data(using: String.Encoding.unicode)!, options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute : NSHTMLTextDocumentType], documentAttributes: nil)
```

This produces a nice (in my opinion) looking quote:
[image]

Comment: good solution, but this dont work for nested quotes, display as one:(